# Couldn't catch response from server with AJAX request

Tags: javascript, ajax, express

I have a simple route like this using AJAX and expressJS but I don't know why the server response can never reach to the client side.
Here is my index.pug

```
    signupbutton.addEventListener('click',function(e){
            var uname = document.getElementById('uname').value;
            var psw = document.getElementById('psw').value;
            var pswRe = document.getElementById('pswRepeat').value;
            var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
            // send uname psw and email to server;
            var user = '' + 'uname=' + window.encodeURIComponent(uname) + '&psw=' + window.encodeURIComponent(psw) + '&email=' + window.encodeURIComponent(email);
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            console.log(user);
            xhttp.onreadystagechange = function() {
                if(this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
                    alert(this.responseText);
                }
            }
            xhttp.open("POST","/SignUpRoute",true);
            xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            xhttp.send(user);
```

Here is my server-side code

```
    app.post('/SignUpRoute', (req,res) => {
        console.log('SignUp Route invoked');
        res.status(200).send('Ok');
    });
```

The onreadystagechange function in the client side doesn't get invoked by the server

Here is the HTML part

```
    div(id='signupTemplate' class='signupTemplate')
        form( class='model-content animate')
            div(class='imgcontainer')
                span(onclick="document.getElementById('signupTemplate').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close PopUp") &#10006;
                img(src='/PICS/logo.png')
                h2(style='font-size:30px; color:rgb(12, 88, 143); font-weight:bold') Online Compiler Signup
            div(class='loginContainer')
                p(style='font-size:20px; font-weight:bold; margin-bottom:-7px; color:rgb(0, 162, 255); margin-left:5px;') Username
                input(type='text' placeholder='Enter username' name='uname' id='uname')
                p(style='font-size:20px; font-weight:bold; margin-bottom:-7px; margin-top:-4px; color:rgb(0, 162, 255); margin-left:5px;') Email address                    
                input(type='text' placeholder='Enter email address' name='email' id='email')           
                p(style='font-size:20px; font-weight:bold; margin-bottom:-7px; margin-top:-4px; color:rgb(0, 162, 255); margin-left:5px;') Password
                input(type='password' placeholder='Enter password' name='psw' id='psw')
                p(style='font-size:20px; font-weight:bold; margin-bottom:0; margin-top:-4px; color:rgb(0, 162, 255); margin-left:5px;') Repeat password
                input(type='password' placeholder='Enter password' name='psw' id='pswRepeat')
                button(type='button' id='templateSignupButton' ) Sign up
```

[Server and client logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAat6.png)
[Network console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8GDA.png)

Comment: What type of element is `signupbutton`? If it's a submit button in a form, you may need to use `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: Can you post the html code as well.

Comment: Phil - the signupbutton is just a regular button, I though about the form things and wondered if the form submits messing  with my route but I figured it out this is not that case

Comment: Your server side is not listening for the message, that post method is a call to actually do a post not received posted data from a client.

Comment: const signupbutton = document.GetElementById('templateSignupButton')

Comment: dont worry about it since the I can see the username password and email address logged on the client console which mean its working just fine, but there still something wrong about the onreadystagechange function :/

Comment: omfg :O I've been thinking all the different possibilities but it just a typo lol I just couldn't tell how much I appreciate your help Phil :D